# Is there an online RobotC IDE?

Tags: robotc, vex

I'm on a Linux chromebook, and am using a Vex robot, and am wondering if there is an online IDE for RobotC that will run my computer?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no RobotC version you can run on your computer as configured - RobotC is currently (as of March 2017) only available for Windows.

Depending on your Chromebook, there may be a way to run Windows software - check out this guide:

https://www.howtogeek.com/173353/how-to-run-windows-software-on-a-chromebook/

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get it to run via wine. If that doesn't work you can definitely get it running in a virtual machine.